# R lapply convert NA's to 0

Tags: r, apply, na

I'm trying to convert a subset of columns from NA's to 0's using the following code.  Unfortunately it turns all the cells to 0's.

```
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:20, col1 = runif(20), col2 = runif(20), col3 = runif(20))

df1[sample(1:20,5),'col1'] <- NA
df1[sample(1:20,5),'col2'] <- NA
df1[sample(1:20,5),'col3'] <- NA

subset1 <- c('col1','col2','col3')

df1[,subset1] <- as.data.frame(lapply(df1[,subset1], function(x) x[is.na(x)] <- 0))
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: the `lapply` function is returning 0. change it to `function(x) { x[is.na(x)] <- 0; x}` or use Jilber's solution

Comment: This subset *is all your columns*. Is that what you meant or in your real data are you only trying to convert *some* NAs to zero and leave others in place?

Answer (score 3):

Try this simple approach

```
df1[is.na(df1),] <- 0
```

Comment: You should do this with `subset1` on the columns.