# Loop through variables to change values

Tags: r, lapply

I'm sure this is a duplicate and an easy problem.

I have a dataframe with strings. All values are character class. I want to convert all rows in all columns to NA if the row has fewer than 5 characters in it. I tried doing the following, but it doesn't work. What am I missing?

```
mydataset <- tibble(
  A = c("Short answer", "Really long answer really long answer", "N/A"),
  B = c("Short answer", "Really long answer really long answer", "n/K"),
  C = c("Really super long answer I want to keep", ".?", "Short")
)
str(mydataset)

lapply(mydataset, function(x) { nchar(x) < 5 <- NA; x})  # incorrect number of arguments to "<<-"
```

h/t [R lapply convert NA's to 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19848963/r-lapply-convert-nas-to-0) and [Delete rows with less than 7 Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23481313/delete-rows-with-less-than-7-characters)

Comment: I think you simply need to subset x by the condition you already set up, e.g., `x[nchar(x) < 5]`. Have not thought through if there are any caveats but for the basic understanding this should be the right direction.

Comment: Of course - so simple :) `mydataset <- lapply(mydataset, function(x) { x[nchar(x) < 5] <- NA; x})`

Comment: `is.na(x) <- nchar(x) < 5`.